# Open Multiple Tabs Without Cookies Persisting

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

For a project of mine I'm running multiple Puppeteer browsers. I'm trying to reduce my CPU/memory consumption by replacing my multiple browsers with one single browser and multiple tabs.

I've tried the following, but cookies seem to stay the same among all tabs in the same browser:

```
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const page = await context.newPage()
const context2 = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const page2 = await context2.newPage();
```

Am I just using contexts wrong?

Comment: I think I'm missing something because you talk about using many tabs but the code you shared has to contexts. Are you talking about tabs or contexts?

Comment: Tabs, I was trying to use contexts to ensure that each new tab had different cookies.

Comment: Tabs will share cookies as normal browser does.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Nope, cookies are shared between tabs, but you can add cookies to the tab before navigation and remove them from the new tabs. However, this will be problematic if you're running tabs in parallel